# How to make bit wise XOR in C

Tags: c, bit, xor

I'm trying to get into C programming, and I'm having trouble writing a bitwise XOR function with only `~` and `&` operators. Example: `bitXor(4, 5) = 1`. How can I achieve this?

So far I have this:

```
int bitXor(int x, int y) {

    return z;
}
```

Comment: I want to write it with only ~ and &

Comment: An empty function that returns an undeclared variable doesn't count as real effort, IMHO. Did you try writing out the truth tables? Tried different combinations of boolean functions on test inputs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Well, let's think about this. What does XOR do?

```
x   y    XOR
------------
0   0     0
1   0     1
0   1     1
1   1     0
```

So how do we turn that into a function?
Let's think about AND, and the inverse order of AND (~x&~y) (this happens to be NOR):

```
              (~x&~y)
 x   y   AND    NOR   
 ---------------------
 0 & 0  = 0      1    
 1 & 0  = 0      0 
 0 & 1  = 0      0
 1 & 1  = 1      0
```

Looking at those two outputs, it's pretty close, all we have to do is just NOR the two previous outputs (x AND y) (x NOR y) and we'd have the solution!

```
  (a)       (b)    ( a NOR b )
x AND y   x NOR y    ~a & ~b
-------------------------------
   0         1          0
   0         0          1
   0         0          1
   1         0          0
```

Now just write that out:

```
a = ( x & y )
b = ( ~x & ~y )
XOR'd result = (~a & ~b)
```

BINGO!
Now just write that into a function

```
int bitXor(int x, int y) 
{
    int a = x & y;
    int b = ~x & ~y;
    int z = ~a & ~b;
    return z;
}
```

Comment: killer explanation...!

Answer (score 27):

Using [NAND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic) logic:

```
int bitNand(int x, int y)
{
    return ~ (x & y);
}

int bitXor(int x, int y)
{
    return bitNand( bitNand(x, bitNand(x, y)),
                    bitNand(y, bitNand(x, y)) );
}
```

Or:

```
int bitXor(int x, int y)
{
    return ~( (x & y) | (~x & ~y) );
}
```

Or:

```
int bitXor(int x, int y)
{
    return (x & ~y) | (~x & y);
}
```

Of course this is easier:

```
int bitXor(int x, int y)
{
    return x ^ y;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is easily seen that

```
x ^ y = (x | y) & ~(x & y)
```

so it remains to express `|` by only `&` and `~`. De Morgan's laws tell us

```
x | y = ~(~x & ~y)
```

Comment: Straight forward and Simple

Answer (score 0):

> I want it to write it only with ~ and &

That counts for NAND gates, right? After studying this [circuit diagram:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aXOR_from_NAND.svg)

```
int z = ~ ((~(a & ~(a & b)) & (~(b & ~(a & b)));
```

The same applies for the non-bitwise, i. e. logic one as well, just substitute `!` instead of the `~`.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a bitwise XOR operation in c using the `^` operator.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP is explicitly asking for doing XOR with only `~` and `&`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int bitXor(int x, int y) {
  return ~(~(~x & y) & ~(x & ~y));
}
```

explanation:

```
x ^ y = (~x & y) | (x & ~y) = ~(~(~x & y) & ~(x & ~y))
```

The last procedure is making use of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score -3):

```
int xorro(a, b)
{
    if (a == b)
        return 0;
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: the question was for a bitwise XOR, not a logical XOR... also it requested use of only `&` and `~`