# Swap two variables with XOR

Tags: c++, xor

With the following method we can swap two variable `A` and `B`

```
A = A XOR B
B = A XOR B
A = A XOR B
```

I want to implement such a method in C++ that operate with all types (int, float, char, ...) as well as structures. As we know all types of data including structures take a specific space of memory, for example 4 bytes, 8 bytes

In my opinion this method for swapping must work with all types excluding pointer based types, It should swap memory contents, that is bits, of two variables

**My Question**
I have no idea how can I implement such a method in C++ that works with structures (those does not contain any pointers). Can any one please help me?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar you are right sir, but I do not want to use an additional variable

Comment: Just use std::swap.

Comment: @harold No, for this question I want to swap two structures

Comment: You already have such a function at your disposal.  It's called `std::swap(...)`.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/

Comment: @LuchianGrigore You are correct sir, but I want to implenemt my own functon that uses XOR

Comment: If you want to implement your own function... do so. If you encounter problems, ask a specific question here.

Comment: @ABFORCE And *why* don't you want to use temporary variable?

Comment: @cmaster Or move-ctors, which will make this operation *a lot* faster using temporary variable than XORing their contents.

Comment: @Spook I have to disagree on the speed here, because you can do the XOR trick with the largest possible type which makes it faster than moving. Moving is only faster than deep copying.

Comment: "you can suppose this is a school assignment :)" - then attempt your homework before asking others to do it.

Comment: The real problem is that this doesn't work in all cases.  Any swap
routine has to handle cases where the code calls the function
with both arguments referring to the same variable, along the
lines of `std::swap( a, a )`.  The xor algorithm doesn't work in
this case, and so is useless as a general swap routine.

Comment: @cmaster Imagine a class, which holds 10 Mb of resources, but shares them with its other intstances. If you ignore the class logic and XOR them out, you will have 3x10Mb of XORing. The move constructor, in turn, would only copy a few pointers. This is theoretical situation, of course, but you get the point.

Comment: @Spook No, you will have a very fast XOR of `sizeof(class)` if you apply the XOR trick to the class. Since it ignores the logical contents of the class, the XOR trick won't chase down the managed memory, it will simply exchange the pointers.

Comment: @cmaster `sizeof(class)` = 10 Mb. Other instances keeps pointers to data in this class (by design). Apart from long working, this may also damage the classes. IMO, omitting move/copy ctors or assignment operators during such exchange is also a bad idea.

Comment: @Spook If `sizeof(class)` == 10 MB, a correct move constructor must nevertheless touch all 10 MB. Move can only be faster than copy if there is something that is *not* included within the object itself, i. e. allocated on the heap. But we are getting way off-topic here.

Comment: @cmaster Which might produce completely nonsensical results. For example, if the structure contains a pointer to part of itself, swapping this way will result in each structure containing a pointer to part of the other!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Now I get what Spook was driving at. It just never occurred to me that someone might declare such a huge class and only use small parts of it, leaving the rest uninitialized. To my brain, objects are always small (big data being allocated dynamically by them), and fully initialized (the whole thing being in a perfectly defined state at all times)... I guess, if you have a 10 MB class that does not use large parts of its allocated space, it's much more pressing to refactor it into something sensible than to think about the performance of a swap operation on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is easily reduced to xor-swap buffers of raw memory. Something like that.

```
void xorswap(void *a, void *b, size_t size);
```

That can be implemented in terms of `xorswap`s of primitive types. For example:

```
void xorswap(void *a, void *b, size_t size)
{
    if (a == b)
        return; //nothing to do

    size_t qwords = size / 8;
    size_t rest = size % 8;

    uint64_t *a64 = (uint64_t *)a;
    uint64_t *b64 = (uint64_t *)b;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < qwords; ++i)
        xorswap64(a64++, b64++);
    uint8_t *a8 = (uint8_t*)a64;
    uint8_t *b8 = (uint8_t*)b64;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < rest; ++i)
        xorswap8(a8++, b8++);
}
```

I leave the implementation of `xorswap64()` and `xorswap8()` as an exercise to the reader.

Also note that to be efficient, the original buffers should be 8-byte aligned. If that's not the case, depending on the architecture, the code may work suboptimally or not work at all (again, an exercise to the reader ;-).

Other optimizations are possible. You can even use [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) to unroll the last loop, but I don't know if it is worth it. You'll have to profile it to know for sure.

Comment: As I pointed out in the comments already: It is even dangerous to supply such a function. It is not guaranteed to do anything remotely correct on all structs.

Comment: To make this more generic, you might want to mix in `CHAR_BIT`, or at least use `sizeof(uint64_t)` instead of `8`.

Comment: @cmaster: Yes, it is dangerous, but so it is `memcpy()`. I would never use this code in a real program (I doubt it will give any advantage over the temporary), but it is good as a programming exercise.

Comment: The real problem is that it doesn't actually work.  Try it when `a` == `b` (a situation which occurs in most of the real uses of swap).

Comment: @Angew: Well, in theory you are right, of course. But in practice, `CHAR_BIT` is 8 for most architectures that most people care about. If `CHAR_BIT` were, say, 7, then I don't know how the compiler would implement `uint8_t` or even `uint64_t`.

Comment: And of course, using `unsigned long long`, rather than `uint64_t`, will result in better portability.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Oh! do you mean when the memory blocks are the same. An easy check, or if you prefer, you can check for that in the `xorswap64()` and `xorswap8()` helper functions.

Comment: @cmaster: This trick will work correctly on trivially copyable structs. The C++ standard gives you the freedom to rely on that, or to shoot yourself in the foot if it isn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It works OK on equal values, but not on overlapping memory. But that's so for memcpy() too, and I've been known to rely on that.

Comment: @david.pfx: My function does not access memory beyond the given `size`. If you call it this way `xorswap(&s1, &s2, sizeof(s1))`, being `s1` and `s2` of the same (trivially copyable) type, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Bitwise XOR` `"^"` in **C** to XOR two bits. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375808/how-to-make-bit-wise-xor-in-c) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Bitwise_XOR_.22.5E.22). Now to **XOR** 'a' and 'b' start XORing from the east significant bit to the most significant bit.